# Java azure-messaging-servicebus - turn off logs

Tags: java, slf4j, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-subscriptions, slf4j-api

I am using following library to connect to my Azure Service Bus through Java application

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-messaging-servicebus</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I am able to successfully connect to the Service bus. But my console is flooded with Azure messaging service bus logs which I want to turn off

I cannot remove the logger implementation in my project as I need that for other modules

Following is the sample logs that I receive

```
DEBUG   2021-05-31 10:55:30.184 [reactor.] (): Using Slf4j logging framework
DEBUG   2021-05-31 10:55:30.796 [com.azur] (): connectionId[[id, UNINITIALIZED]]: State {}
INFO    2021-05-31 10:55:30.801 [com.azur] (): namespace[[, host]] entityPath[{}]: Setting next AMQP channel.
INFO    2021-05-31 10:55:30.801 [com.azur] (): namespace[[, host, 0]] entityPath[{}]: Next AMQP channel received, updating {} current subscribers
DEBUG   2021-05-31 10:55:30.809 [com.azur] (): connectionId[[id, UNINITIALIZED]]: State {}
INFO    2021-05-31 10:55:30.810 [com.azur] (): # of open clients with shared connection: [1]
Starting the Service Bus processorINFO    2021-05-31 10:55:30.834 [com.azur] (): [Topic name , Subscription name]: Creating consumer for link '{}'
INFO    2021-05-31 10:55:30.839 [com.azur] (): Requesting a new AmqpReceiveLink from upstream.
INFO    2021-05-31 10:55:30.853 [com.azur] (): connectionId[[id, host, 5671]]: Creating and starting connection to {}:{}
```

How can I turn off the Azure Service Bus logs only?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried below suggestion from https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-java/issues/255?

Logger.getLogger("com.microsoft.azure.servicebus").setLevel(Level.OFF);